# How can you find closest value of a given number to a bunch of other numbers in java?

Tags: java, average

I Have to do this program:
Ask user for 5 numbers between 0-15.
Find the average of those 5 given numbers.
Find the closest number to the average number from the 5 numbers given.
I know how to ask the user, find average, but I dont know how to find the closest number.Language:Java only.

Comment: If you have a list (or array) of numbers already, why don't you just loop over them and for each number, calculate the difference between that number and the average - and then you have a variable that keeps track of which number is closest to the average.  If you check a number and it's closer to the average than the closest number you've found so far, update the variable.

Comment: If you know how to calculate the average correctly then it should't be too hard to figure out how to get the closest number. A for loop would be a good start

Answer (score 1):

Good to hear that you have figured out most of the problem. Now the fun part. It seems like you are starting with java, so I won't write the code for you (for you sake :) ), I can only help you understand the underlying logic that you would be implementing.

So you have the `average` and the 5 numbers. How can you figure out how close or far 2 numbers are to another 3rd number? It's like measuring distance you find out the difference. Easy right?

So what you have to do is you take the average and you subtract the 5 numbers from the average. Now the result may come in negative as some numbers can be greater than average.

For example if 12 is average and you have 11 and 15, you can see `12-11=1` and `12-15=-3`. So the latter result is smaller but 11 is actually the closer one.

So getting the lowest value isn't the solution. What you have to get is the magnitude. You can do 2 easy work around,

1. You write an `if` condition to check if it is negative. If negative then you multiply it by -1 making it positive.
2. You can use a built in math function, `java.lang.Math.abs(yourValue)` it will return the absolute value of `yourValue`.

Now every value you have would be positive. You have `average` and a number. You find out difference and you save it. You move on to the next number. You do the same and compare to the previously saved number and if it is less that the previous one you save it to the new one.

Now how would you know for which number you got the lowest difference (you know of course but how to make the machine know that)? You can save it in an 2 indexed array, you can save it in a different variable, your wish.

I think you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array in which the numbers are, you have to sort it to find the number thats closest to your value.

consider something like this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-closest-number-array/

```
// Java program to find element closet to given target.
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*; 

class FindClosestNumber { 
  
// Returns element closest to target in arr[] 
public static int findClosest(int arr[], int target) 
{ 
    int n = arr.length; 

    // Corner cases 
    if (target <= arr[0]) 
        return arr[0]; 
    if (target >= arr[n - 1]) 
        return arr[n - 1]; 

    // Doing binary search  
    int i = 0, j = n, mid = 0; 
    while (i < j) { 
        mid = (i + j) / 2; 

        if (arr[mid] == target) 
            return arr[mid]; 

        /* If target is less than array element, 
           then search in left */
        if (target < arr[mid]) { 
     
            // If target is greater than previous 
            // to mid, return closest of two 
            if (mid > 0 && target > arr[mid - 1])  
                return getClosest(arr[mid - 1],  
                              arr[mid], target); 
              
            /* Repeat for left half */
            j = mid;               
        } 

        // If target is greater than mid 
        else { 
            if (mid < n-1 && target < arr[mid + 1])  
                return getClosest(arr[mid],  
                      arr[mid + 1], target);                 
            i = mid + 1; // update i 
        } 
    } 

    // Only single element left after search 
    return arr[mid]; 
} 

// Method to compare which one is the more close 
// We find the closest by taking the difference 
//  between the target and both values. It assumes 
// that val2 is greater than val1 and target lies 
// between these two. 
public static int getClosest(int val1, int val2,  
                                     int target) 
{ 
    if (target - val1 >= val2 - target)  
        return val2;         
    else 
        return val1;         
} 

// Driver code 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9 }; 
    int target = 11; 
    System.out.println(findClosest(arr, target)); 
} 
}
```

Since you didn't specify, I assumed you'd have an array with the numbers in it.
When working with lists instead you got functions you could use for doing this a somewhat easier.

Comment: This solution is way to complicated for this simple task. We're talking 5 numbers in the array.

Comment: I guess you're right. They didn't include negative values either. my bad. Just wanted to show some kind of an example of what i was talking about.